# In_array bug: the first element will be always evaluate to true even if it is already present in the array

Tags: php, arrays, json, comparison

Here's my problem:

```
function parse_xml($url) {
    $fileContents= file_get_contents($url);
    $simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents, null
        , LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $json = json_encode($simpleXml);
    return $json;
}

function gk_install_data() {

    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type'   => 'jobs_api'
    );

    $latestjobs = get_posts( $args );


    $jobtitle = [];
    foreach ($latestjobs as $latestjob) {
        $jobtitle[] = $latestjob->post_title;
    }

    $jsonto = parse_xml('something.html');

    $json_a = json_decode($jsonto, true);

    foreach ($json_a['Job'] as $job => $jobvalue) {

        if (is_array($jobvalue["JobShortDescription"])) {
            $jobdesc = 'Nothing interesting';
        } else {
            $jobdesc = $jobvalue["JobShortDescription"];
        }
        
        if (!in_array($jobvalue["JobTitle"], $jobtitle, true)) {
            $my_jobs_api = array(
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_content' => '<!-- wp:lazyblock/content {"content":"'.$jobdesc.'"} /-->',
                'post_title' => $jobvalue["JobTitle"],
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => 'jobs_api'

            );
            wp_insert_post( $my_jobs_api );
        }
        
    }


}

gk_install_data();
```

I'm parsing an XML file and I turned it into a JSON file.

The idea is to post it to my DB (WordPress) with the function wp_insert_post.

So far so good, it works, except for a very disturbing detail: I don't want any duplicate item, so I'm checking if a field of the array (post_title) is already present in the other array (within a for-each loop) with the function in_array, but for some reason after the first time that I run the code (that will trigger the insert function), the very first value is always returning a true statement so it will always insert within the DB.

I have no idea why, the only difference that I can see (and that's the reason why I added a true value for the third parameter, which is the strict mode) is that the first title is a string "Test vacancy " with space at the very end.

I will describe the problem from another angle:

```
foreach ($json_a['Job'] as $job => $jobvalue) {

    if (!in_array($jobvalue["JobTitle"], $jobtitle, true)) {
        echo "problem";
    } else {
        echo "solution";
    }

}
```

If I run this snippet, the first string that will be print will be "problem" and then "solution".

Even after the posts will be inserted into the DB, when all of them will have the very same title, the first post will be always insert so the first post_title even if it will be equal to the element inserted in the DB will be evaluated as false and re-insert into the DB.

Any Idea?

UPDATE:

var_dump(array_values($jobtitle));

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "Recruitment Consultant"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "Product Manager"
  [2]=>
  string(69) "Ondernemende avonturier (starter/starter+) voor uitbouwen nieuw label"
  [3]=>
  string(12) "Webdeveloper"
  [4]=>
  string(14) "Office manager"
  [5]=>
  string(15) "Dummy vacancy 1"
  [6]=>
  string(15) "Dummy vacancy 2"
  [7]=>
  string(15) "Dummy vacancy 3"
  [8]=>
  string(15) "Dummy vacancy 4"
  [9]=>
  string(15) "Dummy vacancy 5"
  [10]=>
  string(20) "Vacature test Jasper"
  [11]=>
  string(12) "Test vacancy"
}
```

Duplicate item:

string(13) "Test vacancy "

Comment: I think we need to see the contents of `$jobtitle`. You could also try `$jobtitle[$latestjob->post_title] = $latestjob->post_title;` and instead of `in_array` do `isset($jobtitle[$jobvalue["JobTitle"]])`.

Comment: Also strict is only for strict type checking, if the non array values are all strings it will not change anything. [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#refsect1-function.in-array-parameters)

Comment: @cOle2 I will post it!

Comment: @cOle2 posted it

Comment: Ok so `Test Vacancy ` is not the same as `Test Vacancy`. Is there something that is `trim()`ing the values before insertion to the DB?

Comment: Actually not, probably a wordpress native function I would say. I would need to trim after the loop I suppose

Comment: That makes sense. Instead of just `trim()` you may want to match whatever WP is doing to clean/sanitize the post_title. Possibly it's `sanitize_post_field()` but I'm not into WP.